# Input signal types in verilog

Tags: verilog

This is a signal diagram of a transmitter. I don't know the mean of parts are shown in the image. What kind of signals are they? What are their meanings?
[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Essentially those figures are describing **uncertainty**.

For the *Send* signal it could be transitioning from high-to-low anywhere in that region, for the *PDin* bus, any of the eight signals could be transitioning, low-to-high or high-to-low, in that region.

What it's telling you is that those signals are not valid during that time. Once *Send* goes high, the next positive edge of *Clk* will sample the parallel data on *PDin*. Then the serial data, MSB first, will be clocked out by *SCout* and *SDout*.

Comment: My aim is to detect first high of Send. Then get the PDin with that positive edge of Clk. am I right?

Comment: @ffttyy Correct, you want Clk & Send.